# Is a real-symmetric matrix diagonalizable by a special-orthogonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, determinant, diagonalization

Suppose I have a real-symmetric matrix $X$. The spectral theorem guarantees that $X = O^T D O$ for some orthogonal matrix $O$ and diagonal matrix $D$. However, I would like to be able to diagonalize $X$ by a special-orthogonal matrix $\tilde{O}$ with determinant $1$. Is this possible in general?

The best I can come up with is that this is always possible in vector spaces of odd dimension. If $\dim(V) = 2k+1$, then, in the case that $\det(O) = -1$, I can write $\tilde{O} = -O$, and this is a special orthogonal matrix since
$$\det(\tilde{O}) = (-1)^{2k+1}\det(O) = (-1)^{2k+2} = 1,$$
and furthermore, we have: $X = (-O)^T D (-O) = \tilde{O}^T D \tilde{O}$. This argument breaks down for even dimensional vector spaces since then you would need to introduce complex numbers and go to special-unitaries rather than special-orthogonals.

---

In a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246878/symmetric-matrices-that-arent-diagonalizable-by-a-special-orthogonal-matrix), it was mentioned that you can express $X$ in a different basis so that the determinant of the orthogonal diagonalizing matrix switches from $-1$ to $+1$. However, it seems like this would only work if such a basis transformation is itself described by a special-orthogonal matrix, and it seems like this isn't the case in general. Moreover, I would like to not have to modify $X$ at all, except potentially via conjugation by a special-orthogonal matrix.

Comment: If $\det O=-1,$ simply replace one line of $O$ by its opposite.

Comment: you can also permute columns one and two of $O$ which will change the sign of its determinant

Comment: The linked answer isn't expressing $X$ in a different basis; it's saying that $O$ itself is an (ordered) basis, and can be replaced by a different basis $\tilde O$.

Comment: Ah, yeah I greatly misunderstood the answer to the question I linked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user8675309 Not columns but lines (I did the same mistake before). Because here, $X = O^T D O$ and not as usual $D = O^T X O.$